# SQL Azure and Full-Text Catalogs, Indexes and Searching

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Does SQL Azure supports Full-Text catalogs and indexes?

Comment: Last year, I'm positive I saw a post indicating it would be available Q1 2013 which has obviously been and gone. I haven't heard anything since though

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced it will help, but you can vote for it here: http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/169379-data-management-sql-database/suggestions/405464-support-full-text-indexing Not sure how much MS takes account of this though

Comment: Full text search is now in public preview for SQL Azure. You may want to check the recent announcement here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2015/04/29/microsoft-announces-azure-sql-database-elastic-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse-azure-data-lake.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of August 2014, Microsoft is offering a Search-as-a-Service named **Azure Search**:

> Azure Search is a search-as-a-service solution that allows developers
> and cloud architects to embed a sophisticated search experience into
> web and mobile applications without having to worry about the
> complexities of full-text search and without having to deploy,
> maintain, or manage any infrastructure.
>
> With Azure Search, a developer
> can enable the power of searching data in their application, reduce
> the complexity around managing and tuning a search index, and get up
> and running quickly using familiar interfaces and a consistent
> platform.

See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search

**Update:**

As of April 30, 2015 - Full Text Search is available in Preview for SQL Azure. See http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/30/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/

Comment: It's worth mentioning that having SQL Azure work with Azure Search is not "Plug and Play". There is no trick to bind the Azure Search service to an Azure Sql database with change tracking (like in a Sql server machine running on-prem). It takes a bit of code to push the changes from the database to the Azure Search service.

I would expect MS to add such a feature sometime soon. that would make the Azure Search service a very attractive component in the Azure service stack.

Comment: Full-text search is now supported in SQL Azure, here is the link to an example of its advantages, limitations http://sqlindepth.com/full-text-search-in-sql-azure

Comment: If you need full richness of search features in Azure Search, but want to use Azure SQL as the primary data store, we now provide a convenient way to connect your database to your search service. Take a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers-2015-02-28/. This can also be configured in the portal with just a few clicks.

Answer (score 16):

SQL Azure Database [does not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336281.aspx) currently (January 2014) support [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). Many requiring this functionality have opted to use [Lucene.NET](https://nuget.org/packages/Lucene.net/) instead. There's a useful overview of Lucene.NET plus code samples below:

[Lucene.NET Overview and Code Samples](http://leoncullens.nl/post/2012/11/18/Full-Text-Search-on-Azure-with-LuceneNET.aspx)

**EDIT - October 2015:**

[Full-Text Search is now available in Azure SQL Database (GA)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/)

Comment: Is this supporting as of now? or still not?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they recently added the feature:

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/30/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/

Answer (score 0):

The feature is not in preview anymore and is generally available. More [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/general-availability-azure-sql-database-full-text-search/).